# How to add a filter to an EditTex?

Tags: java, android

create class InputFilterMix to add special character which i want to refuse it

```
public class InputFilterMix implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, Spanned spanned, int i2, int i3) {
        if (isCharacter(charSequence.toString())) {
            return "";
        } else if (charSequence.toString().matches("\\d*")) {
            return "";
        }
        return charSequence.toString();
    }

    private boolean isCharacter(String s) {
        return s.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9-' '-\u0621-\u064A]");
    }
}
```

then i added this to myActivity to implement InputFilterMix on

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private EditText name;

    InputFilterMix inputFilterMix = new InputFilterMix();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);

        name.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{inputFilterMix});
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: the filter does not work it accept special character , sometimes in other screen does not accept  space .

Answer (score 0):

Your matching test is done on the string **going to replace** but you want to check the replacement text instead.

Try this code :

```
public class InputFilterMix implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, Spanned spanned, int i2, int i3) {
        final CharSequence replacementText = charSequence.subSequence(i, i1);
        final CharSequence replacedText = spanned.subSequence(i2, i3);

        if (isCharacter(replacementText.toString())) {
            return "";
        } else if (replacementText.toString().matches("\\d*")) {
            return "";
        }
        return replacedText.toString();
    }

    private boolean isCharacter(String s) {
        return s.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9-' '-\u0621-\u064A]");
    }
}
```